# Is anyone using the last but one layer of a deep neural networks for classification or search?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

According to the paper "[Return of the Devil in the Details: Delving Deep into Convolutional Networks](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/deep_eval/)" the last but one layer in a deep neural network trained on a very large dataset can be used as semantic representations of objects in the same domain but from different smaller datasets. I was wondering if someone has experience with using the last but one layer as features for search or classification tasks.